# Error while Building initramfs on linux 4.4 on Amazon EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, initrd

All,

I downloaded the kernel source tree 4.4.66(from kernel.org) and trying to build the kernel and initramfs from this. Kernel built fine but initramfs is not building properly.

By the I am trying this on Amazon AWS EC2 ubuntu instance

4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
    ubuntu@:~/linux_4.4/linux-4.4.66$ mkinitramfs -o initrd.img
    W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
    cp: cannot open '/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi' for reading: Permission denied
```

Any idea how to overcome this problem ?

Comment: If you're trying to build an initramfs archive, then why are you (mis)naming the output file `initrd.img`?  A ramfs is not the same as a (deprecated) ramdisk (despite the errors in the mkinitramfs man page; kernel documentation overrules it).  Did you bother to read the error messages that you posted?  Did you check the permissions of the problem file?

Comment: @sawdust Name doesn't matter. It's sometimes useful to keep the name of the file for sake of simplicity.

Comment: If you have open-iscsi installed, and there is indeed a "/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi" file, then it's a permission problem, since the default permission for that file on many distros is 600. Just use sudo to change the permissions of this file to 644, unless you're worried about system security. Or do your "mkinitramfs" as root?